# Boolean value switch/invert

Tags: php, boolean

Is there a function for switching/inverting `boolean` value in PHP?

Like... a shortcut for:

```
if($boolean === true){
    $boolean = false;
}else{
    $boolean = true;
}
```

Comment: http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Yes:

```
$boolean = !$boolean;
```

if it's not a boolean value, you can use the ternary construction:

```
$int = ($some_condition ? 1 : 2); // if $some_condition is true, set 1
                                  // otherwise set 2
```

Comment: `$bool = !$bool` would turn *true* to *false*, but will it turn *false* to *true*?

Comment: This code is excellent. It's so simple, and i would never have thought of it!

Comment: Is there a way to do that kind of code with a third option?

Comment: @Richard what kind of way are you looking for? What should it do/not do?

Comment: I was after some code a bit like the ternary one but thinking about it now, I know what i was after isn't possible I don't know why I didn't realise that yesterday, I think I was reading it wrong.

Answer (score 10):

If you want the shortest possible code, XOR the boolean with 1:

```
$boolean ^= 1;
```

Strictly this returns an int not a boolean. It doesn't work the same way as `$boolean = !$boolean` (and is slightly less efficient) but for most purposes it should do the job.

Comment: I did 1 million iterations, and XOR took 0.25 seconds, while the logic negation 0.28. So, although it doesn't work the same way, it could be more efficient.

Comment: PHP8 : this will CAST the boolean to int! my phpunit tests are all broken because of this

Answer (score 9):

What about using the Absolute Value function `abs()` , $val can be "1" or "0" and you want to invert it:

```
$val = abs($val-=1);
```

The logic:

Always subtracting "1" from the number and eliminating the "sign".

```
1 - 1 = 0
abs(0) = 0

0 - 1 = -1
abs(-1) = 1
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use `!` to invert the result so it can be like: 
 $boolean                        =      !(bool)$result;

Answer (score 2):

I compared all the ways listed, even the funny ones, to check what is faster, an included one more `$bool = $bool!=true;`:

```
$max=1000000;
$bool=true;

for($t=-microtime(true),$i=0;$i<$max;++$i){
    if($bool) $bool=false; else $bool=true;
}//Time 0.3589
echo sprintf("Time %.4F\n",$t+microtime(true));

for($t=-microtime(true),$i=0;$i<$max;++$i){
    switch($bool){ case true: $bool=false; break; default: $bool=true;}
}//Time 0.4387
echo sprintf("Time %.4F\n",$t+microtime(true));

for($t=-microtime(true),$i=0;$i<$max;++$i){
    $bool = !$bool;
}//Time 0.2833
echo sprintf("Time %.4F\n",$t+microtime(true));

for($t=-microtime(true),$i=0;$i<$max;++$i){
    $bool = $bool!=true;
}//Time 0.2803
echo sprintf("Time %.4F\n",$t+microtime(true));Time 0.2803

for($t=-microtime(true),$i=0;$i<$max;++$i){
    $bool = ($bool-1)*(-1);
}//Time 0.3047
echo sprintf("Time %.4F\n",$t+microtime(true));

for($t=-microtime(true),$i=0;$i<$max;++$i){
    $bool = abs($bool-1);
}//Time 1.2211
echo sprintf("Time %.4F\n",$t+microtime(true));

for($t=-microtime(true),$i=0;$i<$max;++$i){
    $bool ^= 1; //XOR
}//Time 0.2595
echo sprintf("Time %.4F\n",$t+microtime(true));

for($t=-microtime(true),$i=0;$i<$max;++$i){
    $bool = $bool?0:1;
}//Time 0.3253
echo sprintf("Time %.4F\n",$t+microtime(true));
```

Curiously, the obvious seems to be the 3rd in performance. ***XOR*** is a bit faster than logical complement (*negation*), and this last seems to be almost similar to the *not equal* operator that I added to the party.

Time to swap values 1 millon times:

1. `$bool ^= 1` -> 0.2595 seconds
2. `$bool = $bool!=true` -> 0.2803 seconds
3. `$bool = !$bool` -> 0.2833 seconds
4. `$bool = ($bool-1)*(-1)` -> 0.3047 seconds
5. `$bool = $bool?0:1` -> 0.3253 seconds
6. *if* -> 0.3589 seconds
7. *switch* -> 0.4387 seconds
8. `$bool = abs($bool-1)` -> 1.2211 seconds

Answer (score 0):

One touch pick of boolean:

$detector = !$picker = $detector;

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in one line :

```
<?php
$val = 0 
$val = $val ==1?0:1;  
?>
```

Comment: Assuming those `$val` values, you could do `$val = $val?0:1;`

Answer (score -9):

bool can be either TRUE or FALSE.

usage : **(boolean)$red =  varbool(false);**
          echo $red;

for true it will return zero and one for false

```
function varbool($val){ 

    $val +=(-1);
    $val *= (-1);   
    return $val;
}
```

Comment: Just one question... **why**? What's wrong with `!`? (I'm tempted to -0.5 for reinventing the wheel and -0.5 for doing so very poorly)

Comment: Elegance is the name after your first name and before your last name, if you have three names.

Comment: This answer should be archived. It has historical value.

Comment: I don't see the historical value as it never answered the question.

Comment: @SteveBuzonas The historical value comes from the fact it's so damn funny.