# PHP - toggle state

Tags: php, math

The problem is simple, but I'm looking for a creative solution.
We meet very often arrays, objects that has a property that can be toggled (it can be active or inactive, 1 or 0).

What I want is a creative solution (a function) to transform 0 to 1, and 1 to 0.

Some examples:

```
// First
if ($state == 1)
{
  $state = 0;
}
else
{ 
  $state = 1; 
}

// Second
$states = array(1, 0);
$state = $states[$state];

// Third
$state = ($state == 1) ? 0 : 1;
```

Is there another, one line solution for this?
Thanks, and enjoy the brainstorming.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603589/boolean-value-switch-invert

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can do:

```
$state = 1 - $state;
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this code : 
`$state = !$state`

Answer (score 1):

If the result is allowed to be a boolean (and it does not have to be an integer swap) you can use the negation operator:

```
<?php
$state = 0;
var_dump(!$state);

$state = 1;
var_dump(!$state);
```

Output:

```
bool(true) 
bool(false)
```

Comment: Good idea. If needed a type cast can be done: (int)(!$state);