# PHP Flip Boolean Value

Tags: php

I have a boolean value that I would like to flip between true and false.  The basic implementation of this is:

```
if ($my_boolean) {
   $my_boolean = false;
}
else {
   $my_boolean = true;
}
```

Is there a way to simplify this and reduce the number of lines of code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boolean value switch/invert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603589/boolean-value-switch-invert)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$my_boolean = !$my_boolean;
```

Comment: This is probably the neatest way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

an alternative just for posterity:

```
$my_boolean = ($my_boolean) ? FALSE : TRUE;
```