# Toggling a boolean in WordPress MySQL query not working

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to toggle a boolean in MySQL using $wpdb->update. It works to toggle a 'false' boolean (0) to 'true' (1), but not the other way around. I'm having a hard time figuring out why.

I'm attempting to toggle is_blue whenever the code runs. Here's my code:

```
// $e_id is set to an integer matching the entry_id value
        
$wpdb->update("table_name", array(
"is_blue" => "1 - is_blue"), array(
"entry_id" => $e_id)
);
```

I've also tried it as:

```
"is_blue" => "NOT is_blue"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boolean value switch/invert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603589/boolean-value-switch-invert)

Comment: Did you found any solutions?